# Bank Statements for Visitor Visa appointment to the UK

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have an upcoming trip to the **UK** from **India** and have scheduled the Visa appointment on priority. I have the jitters before the interview primarily because of my bank statement. My circumstance is as follows.

- I have a stable job as a SDE-3 Amazon. The job fortunately pays more per month than my trip expenses. Around 3 times more to be precise.
- I also have a leave letter from Amazon that will I'm hoping convince the ECO that I have pressing reasons to return.

My question stems from the fact that my salary account is an account that I use mainly as a conduit to receive my salary. (The salary amount is present in my bank statement with the employer name over a six month period). My money from the salary then gets redirected to other sources of investment and a skeletal amount remains in my salary account enough to tend to my day to day.

Will this make it seem like I'm a reckless spender and thereby affect my chances of getting the Visa approved?

Also, if my $100 is my monthly salary, there was a recent deposit of $25 from a friend who owed me the $25. Will this be flagged?

For the last month or so my balance has stayed over 2x my trip expenses. But it has been quite volatile prior to this due to the reasons mentioned above.

Any general advice on what I should be doing to improve my chances are greatly appreciated.

Edit: I can furnish my payslip from my current org.

I can also furnish proof of funds via investment. But not sure what documents to present from banks in India.

Comment: IMHO the $25 transaction is insignificant and won’t be a red flag. What might be a flag is a change in the account profile starting a month or so before your application. Can you provide statements on your other investments to show your overall financial position? Does this answer your question? [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: I second Traveller's point about _providing statements on your other investments to show your overall financial position_ As an aside it almost never makes sense to pay for priority visa fee except it is an absolute emergency or your chances of getting the visa are virtually guaranteed. Paying priority does not change their decision and is nonrefundable.

Comment: If your income is considerably more than your regular living expenses then it would be *un*usual to leave it lying in a current account, and *not* move it into other investments. OTOH it would seem to be normal behaviour to keep money at hand recently to meet the cost of the trip.

Comment: Thank you for your comments... to address @Traveller I can show some of my other investments. The website is not super clear on how I should go about doing that. Do I furnish my Fixed Deposit Summaries from banks and/or should I present my holdings in shares and funds? Is there a more formal process?  My travel date is the 7th of October a standard visa would cut it too close.

Comment: Immigration don't just want to see how much money you have. They want to see your general financial situation, so how much money you spend, how much you save each month etc. You need to provide day-to-day bank statements.

Comment: @DJClayworth Thank you for your response. I intend to provide my Bank Statement but the volatility of balances due to transfer of money from medium to the other is what concerned me.

Comment: Hey Travelbody, did you get your visa then ? Or repayment of the loan got you in trouble? In similar situation here.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in a similar situation before. Make sure you submit the following to justify your financial stability

1. Bank statements
2. Salary Slips of last 6 months
3. Income Tax Returns of previous years
4. Mutual funds/Stock statements/FD statement etc.

In my opinion, you should also write a cover letter explaining about your finances where you can mention about your investing habits and ties to your country. Here is a very good [example](https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/cover-letter-for-uk-visa/) on how to write a cover letter.

PS - It's good that you have opted for priority service. Visitor visas are getting delayed in India. Mine is pending since 4 weeks. Covid 3rd wave is also a risk which might put India back to Red list.

Comment: HI, Thanks for your response and I'm sorry to hear about your visa. Could you please tell me how you documented your Mutual Funds/Stock statements? Thanks! I plan to write a cover letter from the blog you sent me thank you very much.

Comment: Just get the consolidated mutual funds statement from CAMS or Karvy. For stocks you can take from Zerodha or your stock broker.